# BMS for multi cell batteries

Tags: bms

I have several large LG multi-cell batteries. Images & description can be seen here:

I'm wondering if I can use a 14S BMS for each of these batteries in order to keep every cell balanced and in check and run them in the series. 
For example, I want to use 3 of these batteries which has fourteen cells each (total of 42 cells) , so I'd purchase 3x 14s BMS.
Pictures attached show the packs opened containing the 14 cells in two separate packs of 7.
I was wondering if the stock MBMS that you can find a picture below of could be of any use, I doubt it however.
Any advice would be very helpful, thanks in advance!
[image: Enclosed Battery] 
[image: Specs]
[image: Opened enclosure]
[image: Individual cell connection points]
[image: Stock MBMS with the cell]

Answer (score 0):

The multi battery balancers will work, and provided you use the same type and number of cells connected to each similar should not cause issue, if they have different numbers of cells the imbalance in power consumption from the balance PCB's will cause an imbalance on there own,

however treat each like a separate 14S battery in that case, if they have any data or status lines, keep them separate. e.g. via opto-couplers if you need to drive something on another PCB.

Charge rates should be kept in the same order of magnitude of the balancers per cell current limit, if old cells are used, keep it closer to this rating,

If the boards have status outputs such as charged, flat or balancing, I would make use of them to allow you to ramp up your charge / discharge rates if you need it.